# KIVY performance as compared to pyqt's QGraphiscscene

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, kivy

here is a general problem I am struggling with

I am trying to create a pyqt application that basically renders thousands of points in a zoom-able, pannable graph,(think star field where each point represents a star/planet)
There are about 5000 points when fully zoomed out. User is allowed to interact with the items on the scene by zooming, and dragging or panning around. However it is quite choppy and slow as the number of points increase to several thousand.
I would like to make my application to be more responsive especially to user interaction(zoom,dragging and panning)

Currently it seems that the Qgraphicsscene/Qgraphicsview is not very per-formant/fast when there are thousands of points that allow for user interaction.
I am comparing this with [KIVY](http://kivy.org/#home) and wondering if the Qgraphicsscene/Qgraphicsview is the correct technology/toolkit for doing what I want.
Is Qgraphicsscene/Qgraphicsview as powerful/per-formant as what is touted by kivy?

NOTE: 
I'm using with pyqt and python 2.7, and I've only had a cursory read about KIVY

Comment: Instead of Kivy or pyqt, go to Vispy.

Answer (score 0):

With careful use of kivy's graphics api, it could handle 5000 points trivially, since it's just opengl behind the scenes. Panning will certainly be fast, and zooming can be fast or slower (but maybe still easily good enough) depending on how you implement it which in turn depends on what quality you want to preserve. I'm not sure what performance you'd get without being careful beyond basic api usage though, it might be okay. It might also be the case that the qt method could also be much faster with some optimisation or different api usage.

I suppose that if you really think qt is probably just not capable here, I'd recommend giving kivy a try, doing the basic task as simply as you can. It should not be very hard. Then you can compare yourself.